# How to get Android Amazon Web Services (AWS) SDK working with AWS simulation (such as FakeS3)

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cloud

I want to test my Android app using a local AWS simulation package such as FakeS3 before moving to real Amazon S3 servers.

What do you need to change/configure in the AWS SDK (aws-android-sdk) package in order to get it working with FakeS3?

Has anyone already done this and got it working?

Answer (score 1):

As `FakeS3` is simply emulating the S3 service, you should simply be able to create an S3 client and set the endpoint on the client to use your server running FakeS3.  You can refer to the client docs here:

[Source Link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#setEndpoint%28java.lang.String%29)